# Convert VB.Net Textbox input to Time of Day

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am creating an application that needs to allow the user to input a 4-digit text string (ex. 1330 or 0100) and convert that input to the time of day including AM/PM.

examples
1330 = 1:30 PM;
0130 = 1:30 AM

I am unsure what the best way to go about this would be. I am thinking to use a select case or nested ifs; however, I feel as if there is probably a better, quicker way to convert this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use the [DateTimePicker control](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home) from the *Extended WPF Toolkit* or create your own simple user control with for example two fields for the hour and minute parts.

If you want to create your own solution:

- make sure, that the input is always 4 characters long
- create a string from the current date and the entered time stamp
- verify and parse the string with [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- use the new DateTime object to take the time
- use [DateTime.ToString(format,provider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the desired output

The code to parse the user input string:

```
private Function parseTime(ByRef hours as String) as String
    ' TODO: error handling
    Dim timeStamp as String = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), hours.Substring(0, 2),hours.Substring(2, 2))
    Dim dateTime as DateTime
    if (DateTime.TryParse(timeStamp, dateTime)) then
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", dateTime.ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), dateTime.ToString("tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    end if

    return String.Empty

end Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim hoursPM as String = "1330"
Dim hoursAM as String = "0130"
Console.WriteLine(parseTime(hoursPM))
Console.WriteLine(parseTime("errr")) 'empty string indicates error
Console.WriteLine(parseTime(hoursAM))
```

And the output:

```
01:30PM

01:30AM
```